# Vectors that satisfy $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i X_i^\top = I$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{p_i}Y_iY_i^\top = \Sigma(P)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R^d}$. Assume all of the vectors are inside the unite $\ell_2$ ball. Let $P$ be a vector in the probability simplex $\Delta_n$ with $P_i>0$ for all $i$. Consider the second moment matrix $\Sigma(P) = \sum_{i=1}^n P_i X_i X_i^\top$. Assume the $X_i$s are such that $\Sigma(P)$ is full rank. We need to find vectors $Y_1,\dots, Y_n$ such that the following two conditions hold:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i X_i^\top &= I\\
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{p_i}Y_iY_i^\top &= \Sigma(P)^{-1}
\end{align}
We observe that $Y_i=p_i \Sigma(P)^{-1} X_i$ is a solution. Are there any other solutions?